# Zurb Foundation 6: Dropdown JS data-options attribute not working as expected

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using the latest version of ZURB Foundation Flex with ([cdnjs v6.3.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/js/foundation.min.js)). I am using the [dropdown JS component](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown.html) which works absolutely fine out of the box but I am unable to customize it using the inbuilt `data-options=""`, its simply not detecting the options at all. Since I'm using Flex I considered that being a problem so I attempted to add a position class using data options and that option was also ignored.

*Here is my HTML:*

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu-one">
    <li><a href="/" title="">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/" title="">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="link-three">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="dropdown-pane bottom" id="link-three" data-dropdown data-options="data-v-offset: 300px; data-h-offset: 300px;">
    <ul class="menu-two">
      <li><a href="" title="">Link 3 A</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Link 3 B</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Link 3 C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

*And basic JavaScript:*

```
$(document).foundation();
```

I have also tested it in 6.3.0 with no luck and I do believe that this is either a bug or most likely something I'm doing wrong or simply because this may not be supported in flex.

*JsFiddle:*

To make things easier for the community of StackOverflow to answer I've made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/we9dqvqu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not fabulously well documented but you have to change the format of the option to remove the hyphens and "data-" when using the `data-options` attribute. Basically `data-v-offset` ==> `vOffset` e.g.

```
<nav>
  <ul class="menu-one">
    <li><a href="" title="">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="link-three">Link 3 (Dropdown)</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="dropdown-pane bottom" id="link-three" data-dropdown data-options="vOffset:300; hOffset:300;">
    <ul class="menu-two">
      <li><a href="" title="">Link 3 A</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Link 3 B</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Link 3 C</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://simonhayter.co.uk" title="Simon Hayter">SimonHayter.co.uk</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/we9dqvqu/4/)

[Vague documentation, you have to read between the lines](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#configuring-plugins).